# Lucrative vs Profitable

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between `lucrative` and `profitable`? I found this explanation [here](https://www.italki.com/question/348994):

> They are not quite interchangeable, although I just checked a
>   dictionary and it defines "lucrative" simply as "producing wealth;
>   profitable." Nevertheless, I think there's a difference.
>
> "Profitable" is a plain, factual, ordinary word and it's the one you
>   should usually use. It simply means that the contract is expected to
>   make a profit for the company. You can intensify it by saying "very
>   profitable." "Lucrative" carries a sense of great, *possibly
>   excessive* profit. I imagine it being used in a context like this:
>
> "Well, we got the contract! And I can't believe it, they just accepted
>   our numbers for the second and third year without trying to negotiate
>   them down!"
>
> "No kidding! Wow! Well, congratulations! I think we should go out and
>   celebrate, that's going to be a lucrative contract for us!"
>
> By comparison:
>
> "Well, we got the contract. But we had to make some concessions,
>   they're insisting on a 10% reduction for year 2 and a 20% reduction
>   for year 3." "Hmmm. Well, that wasn't what I was hoping for, but it
>   still should be profitable for us."

[This dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lucrative) suggests that they are the same

Comment: If you're a real estate developer you can have a project go bankrupt and still be lucrative (to you).

Comment: @HotLicks, so what does it literally mean?

Comment: Please don't have us go chasing links to other sites' answers; include the text from the other site here and provide a link to it. Anything you do to make it easier on us will increase the odds of you getting an answer here. Note that this site wants you to *include* the research you have done, not just link to it. More important, what dictionaries have you looked up the two words in and why didnt the information found in them resolve your question?

Comment: @user9825893y50932, makes sense. I will correct it

Comment: Vlad, that explanation seems fine to me. Sometimes you have to check more than one dictionary and frankly I dont use the one you linked to. I use Oxford Dictionary Online and it defines [profitable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/profitable) as ' yielding profit or financial gain' and [lucrative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lucrative)  as 'Producing a great deal of profit', which means "very profitable." I hope that helps. See also [OneLook Dictionary](https://www.onelook.com/) which provides links to many dictionaries on one page...

Comment: Also, I wrote that information in a comment and not in an answer, because to me this is a "general reference question", which means it is not considered a good question for this site; in other words, it is off-topic. But I thought I'd help you out, and also point you to the Oxford dictionary and to the OneLook site.

Comment: From a denotative standpoint, "lucrative" and "profitable" are perfect synonyms. The only differences are in the connotative or intangible meaning. The word "lucrative", while being an extreme form of "profitable", also has strong negative/'evil' connotations, probably because we're talking about an amount of money that is excessive to the point of being unethical. The phrase "lucrative mining operation" is natural to me, but the phrase "Indonesia's lucrative pharmaceutical industry" is not, because I would be happy for a developing country to have a highly profitable industry in medicine.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out here that the root derivation of a word is part of what lends implication to its use: the root word for 'money' embedded in lucrative is *lucre*.

From the ODO

**lucre**
*mass noun*
Money, especially when regarded as sordid or distasteful or gained in a dishonourable way.

*‘officials getting their hands grubby with filthy lucre’*

[ODO Definition Link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lucre)

As a result, I'd agree with the idea that 'lucrative' indicates not just greater profitability, but that a *pejorative* secondary connotation is *to be expected* when this word is applied.

Comment: The dictionary you are quoting from is ODO, not OED. They are two very different dictionaries (see [this list](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/148/191178) for information).

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, *lucrative* and *profitable* can function as synonyms. A lucrative business, investment, or product is a priori also profitable. There are, however, certain contexts where English speakers have a preference for one over the other. In only one sense is the difference lexical.

#### Profit with No Money

While *lucrative* is strictly limited to the financial, something can be *profitable* in the more general sense of ‘beneficial, advantageous, worthwhile’:

> A sensor presenting such density would be highly [*profitable*](https://books.google.de/books?id=-W5bBvq70_0C&pg=PA62&dq=%22profitable+for%22+-ministry+-God+-Scripture+-business&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK8PbWzKbaAhUJUlAKHfcGCK84KBDoAQgrMAE) for in vivo experimentations...
>
> For this reason, we hope that our book will give an opportunity to mathematicians working in other fields to get interested in differential equation theory — which can undoubtedly be most [*profitable*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ChXRBgAAQBAJ&pg=PR8&dq=%22profitable+for%22+-ministry+-God+-Scripture+-business&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7zZi2zabaAhUHbVAKHVpgDs04MhDoAQhJMAY) for their own work.
>
> Politics is a zero-sum game—that is, what is electorally [*profitable*](https://books.google.de/books?id=mI1oBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT145&dq=%22profitable+for%22+-ministry+-God+-Scripture+-business&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinjYW60KbaAhUSbVAKHUVeBmw4vgEQ6AEILjAC) for Republicans is electorally challenging for Democrats.

Even with the adverb *electorally*, *lucrative* would not only be totally out of place in these examples, but wrong according to dictionaries. Here, the difference is lexical.

#### Potential vs. Actual

Some maintain that *lucrative* may — but not always — suggest the potential for future profits rather than actual ones.

> This time round the money men at Universal Studios thought they'd spotted the chance for some [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=SC7t6f9be2QC&pg=PT99&dq=%22lucrative+product%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1oXE1qbaAhXSKFAKHbngDVY4ChDoAQhIMAY) product placement…

A particular film offered the opportunity to make money, but in the planning stage, financial gain is potential rather than actual.

Developing countries are often hailed as offering lucrative investment opportunities, so much so that it almost seems a cliché:

> Azerbaijan, Turkmenistan, and Kazakhstan … are welcoming foreign energy companies and offering them [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=-sCpf26vBZ0C&pg=PA145&dq=%22lucrative+investment+opportunities%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz9q3L0abaAhXEPFAKHZdJD_4Q6AEIJTAA) investment opportunities.
>
> A country with a strong economy and [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=q0oEBo-wUU8C&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22lucrative+investment+opportunities%22&source=bl&ots=X1AGuntum7&sig=72tExVR8hjaKjeDBvSNvwttimvY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi83enQ0qbaAhVLbFAKHe1rCOI4FBDoATAJegQIBhAB) investment opportunities will typically have a strong currency because global companies and investors want to buy into that country's investment opportunities.

*Profitable*, however, can just as easily describe such potential:

> Similarly, a country that offers highly [*profitable*](https://books.google.de/books?id=VhkAsLhiKVYC&pg=PA33&dq=%22profitable+investment+opportunities%22+country&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje2p6F1abaAhWMfFAKHeASDjQ4ChDoAQgkMAA) investment opportunities in the export sector will not suffer a lack of foreign capital.
>
> These countries (Japan being one example) may not have enough [*profitable*](https://books.google.de/books?id=YbDtAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22profitable+investment+opportunities%22+country&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr_LmZ1KbaAhVMa1AKHeROBiMQ6AEIVDAI) investment opportunities at home, and they may seek opportunities for investment abroad…

When Apple introduced the iPhone, it entered a new market with a potential for great profits:

> Selling 10 million iPhones in the product's first year not only boosted Apple's profits; it also established the company as a formidable competitor in a [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=UasEAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA415&dq=%22first+year+not+only+boosted+Apple%27s+profits%22+%2210+million%22+%22category+in+which+it+had%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-lI6J2abaAhXSZVAKHQWrCsQQ6AEIJDAA) product category in which it had had no previous experience.

The point here, however, is not the potential in this market sector for Apple, rather that the manufacture of mobile phones was in itself highly profitable, just not yet for Apple. Besides that, the writer had already used the word *profits*, so *lucrative* seemed a better choice, especially since one connotation of the latter word is very large profits.

One writer explains a problem with a strategy to sell iPods directly rather than through its dealer network:

> Apple would have difficulties with a hybrid strategy of selling iPods directly and selling computers through retail channels: the channel partners would not look kindly on losing a [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=EKNoKQ1L4CoC&pg=PA370&dq=%22lucrative+product%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBra7U16baAhXRalAKHeA-BPg4FBDoAQgrMAE) product line and may not commit resources to computer sales.

Again, the money here is real: the iPod is a profitable product line. And if you know anything about how much profit there is over wholesale for an Apple dealer, then you know the amount is not enormous. All this sentence is saying that the iPod made money.

A preference, then, for *lucrative* to describe potential rather than actual profits is not a lexical distinction, but only just that, a preference. In fact, the distinction appears to me less about potential or actual profits, but that when one is talking about foreign investment, the buzzword is more likely to be *lucrative* than *profitable*:

> It is sometimes argued that, even if the company has highly *[profitable](https://books.google.de/books?id=vahDDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA441&dq=%22profitable%20investment%20opportunities%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixzM-b06baAhWDbFAKHRp2Cw4Q6AEILDAB)* investment opportunities, earnings should be distributed and funds should be raised externally to finance the investment.
>
> A vitally important part of the investment process is the search for *[profitable](https://books.google.de/books?id=9GwCgPibTl4C&pg=PA156&dq=%22profitable%20investment%20opportunities%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixzM-b06baAhWDbFAKHRp2Cw4Q6AEIMjAC)* investment opportunities.

In both cases, the investment has not yet been made; in the second case, not yet found. This would suggest that if the preference for *lucrative* for potential profits were a strong one, then that word should appear here. It seems to me that since the topic isn‘t a national economy, then the choice is likely governed solely by the writer’s choice of words.

#### Barely Profitable, Barely Lucrative

*Lucrative* may — but not always — suggest not just a financial venture that turns a profit, but one that makes a great deal of money. Thus beginning in the late 1990s, a [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barely+profitable%2Cbarely+lucrative&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbarely%20profitable%3B%2Cc0) shows that writers began to speak more of a *lucrative sport*, most often football, either American or association (soccer), than a merely *profitable sport*:

> Though it is an American sport and most known about in the US, still it happens to be the most [*lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=RV0ZBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT8&dq=%22lucrative+sport%22+billion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYssO27abaAhVIaVAKHbpcDq0Q6AEIMTAC) sport worldwide with an annual revenue of 9.5 billion dollars, out of which 5 billion dollars comes from television alone.

It should come as no surprise then, that an [NGram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barely+profitable,barely+lucrative&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbarely%20profitable%3B%2Cc0t1;,barely%20profitable;,c0t1;,barely%20profitable;,c0%23t1;,barely%20profitable;,c0t1;,barely%20profitable;,c0) for the strings “barely profitable,” i.e. barely turning a profit over expenses, and “barely lucrative” yielded no results for the latter, which indicates less than 40 hits. When “barely lucrative” is used, however, it is only in the sense of making any money at all:

> Both in grad school, both working full time, but at jobs that were just [*barely lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=NPhNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT115&dq=%22barely+lucrative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_4siB8qbaAhVQbVAKHeB7Br0Q6AEIPjAE) enough to cover our monthly expenses…
>
> Finally, [Marie] Curie evolved a plan: she would enter service as a governess, the only [*barely lucrative*](https://books.google.de/books?id=X7vjCMcM9lQC&pg=PA194&dq=%22barely+lucrative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_4siB8qbaAhVQbVAKHeB7Br0Q6AEIXDAJ) position open to a woman of her social and educational background…

Since these writers are speaking here of struggling to pay for basic human needs, *profitable*, though fiscally accurate, would seem completely out of place.

#### Ill Gotten Gains

If money is earned through criminal activity,  an [NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profitable+drug+trade%2Cprofitable+black+market%2Clucrative+black+market%2C+lucrative+drug+trade%2Clucrative+crime%2Cprofitable+crime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofitable%20drug%20trade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprofitable%20black%20market%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clucrative%20black%20market%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clucrative%20drug%20trade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clucrative%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprofitable%20crime%3B%2Cc0) a preference for *lucrative* over *profitable*, though the preference for the more general *lucrative crime* is fairly new. In the heydey of Al Capone and Bonnie and Clyde, crime was a profitable venture, not a lucrative one. The relatively late date of these preferences, even quite strong ones for “black market” and “drug trade,” suggests minimal influence from the Bible‘s “filthy lucre” (Titus 1.11).

[image]

#### Conclusion

While *profitable* may be used in contexts where money plays no role, when it does, its meaning is less nuanced than *lucrative*. Both *lucrative* and *profitable* start at that magical moment when red turns to black, but *lucrative* can go further. These nuances are revealed through frequency queries of the Google Books corpus, but they are defined by preferences, not by dictionaries. A preference does not mean that someone discussing the illegal drug trade or the black market who uses *profitable* has chosen a poor word, but only that far more writers would choose *lucrative* instead.

Answer (score 0):

The practical distinction turns on the legalistic definition of "profit".  If I create a corporation that borrows $100M to build and sell a hotel, completes the hotel, but then cannot sell it for more than $80M, the corporation will likely go bankrupt, producing no *profit* (much the contrary).

However, if I arrange to receive a $10M "up-front" fee for "managing" the construction, the deal is still quite *lucrative* for me.

This isn't just a matter of the potentially pejorative tilt of "lucrative".  Consider that "profit" is *money that a business earns above what it costs to produce and sell goods and services* [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/profit).  One can operate a "business" which doesn't really "produce" anything -- the accounting sheet shows money in but no real expenditures representing the cost of generating that income.  Such a business may be quite *lucrative*, but technically it's not *profitable*.

Answer (score -3):

By definition (per Oxford Dictionary, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lucrative) Lucrative is a "great deal" of profit whereas profitable can range from a tiny amount to larger.

Comment: Actually, [MW dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lucrative) says of lucrative: "**producing wealth : profitable**". Nowhere on that page does it say 'great deal'. Next time, please link to your sources so others can easily verify them.

Comment: I stand corrected. It was actually the Oxford Dictionary regarding lucrative.

Comment: No problem, please edit your answer (preferably with a link to the ODO).

Answer (score -3):

**Lucrative** is a derivation of **lucre**, a word which a multitude of dictionaries defines as something like *"monetary gain"*.  It in turn springs from the Latin **lucrum**, meaning *profit.*

Most things grow complicated by the introduction of religion, and this case presents no exception. This Bible verse (Titus i,11) has become memorably embedded in the language:

> Whose mouths must be stopped, who subvert whole houses, teaching things which they ought not, for **filthy lucre's** sake.  *(Emphasis added)*  (KJV)

Thus **lucre** and its derivatives have gained a connotation darkened by worldly venality.

**Profit**, which also denotes monetary gain (often the fruit of investment), has a less tarnished reputation.  Although the Old Testament is filled with warnings that wrong-headed people will not **profit** from misdeeds, we get a more neutral sense in Isaiah xxx,5:

> They were all ashamed of a people that could not **profit** them, nor be an help nor **profit**, but a shame, and also a reproach.  (KJV)

This would suggest that in the tradition of language rooted broadly in Judeo-Christian ideas, **profit** is a tolerably good thing - better, at least, then **filthy lucre.**

To bring this back to the OP's question, the difference between **lucre** and **profit** is indeed one of connotation, even though denotatively they mean pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I would like to see real language examples where "lucrative" is used in a sense influenced by "filthy lucre" rather than your supposition of it.